# Without the g flag RegEX return wired output

Tags: php, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

Regex

```
m/(b?)-/ [here no g flag]
```

Sample input

```
a-b-
```

Current matching

```
-
```

Desired matching

```
b-
```

My doubt is about why without a global flag `b-` is not matched

> (b?) is optionally matching literal b

> "-" is matched literal -

finally, I get only `-` this one?

```
$ echo "a-b-" | sed 's/\(b\?\)-/x\u\1/g'
axxB
$ 
$ echo "a-b-" | sed 's/\(b\?\)-/x\u\1/'
axb-
```

In the last sed replacement, the first occurrence of `-` is replaced by x what about the `b-`

Comment: Please add a proper problem statement to your question.  What is the input?  What are you trying to match within that input?

Comment: Without global flag regex will return first match only. Since your regex is `b?-` with optional `b` therefore it returns first `-` from input `a-b-`. When there is a global flag then it will return 2 matches `['-', 'b-']`

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, I want to match "b-" string using "b?-" this regex. Please look at this https://regex101.com/r/8GCQjr/1

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus I will update that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the global flag regex will return first match only. Since your regex is `b?-` with optional `b` therefore it returns first `-` from input `a-b-`.

If you still want to match `b-` even though `-` appears first then you can use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```sh
b?-(?!.*b-)
```

This will match optional `b` followed by a `-` only if there is no `b-` on right hand side since we are using a negative lookahead.

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/aGbZ2z/1)

**If there is no `b-` then it will match first `-`.**

[RexEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/aGbZ2z/2)

Comment: Can you please look at the current question now.?

Comment: Yes I did already and my answer is already addressing both cases. Let me know which case is not covered?

Comment: ? modifier prioritized zero occurrences of a character first, right?. b+- will do the correct job. I have learned something.

Comment: Yes `b-` will also do the job but it won't match `-` in `x-y`

Comment: (b*)- is matching the -b- [- and b-], is there any reverse traversing in regex engine, b* matches any number of occurrences of b and followed the "-" character, but somehow the character "-" in front of the b* is also matched.

Comment: Got it, Engine will never care about the ?,  * modifier zero occurrence matching in the absence of global matching flag. Thank you.

Comment: Regex Engine moves from left to right. If there is no global flag then it will attempt to find first match and stop there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235013/discussion-between-ajil-raju-and-anubhava).